# Start another activity with button

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Im making an chat-app. I have my activity with the xml (the design of the app). What i want to do is when i click my button "Connecta", I want my other java class to run (ChatClient). But i cant get it to work.

Also, how do i get my textfield in ChatClient to be my Textfield in Main activity(xml)?

Comment: ChatClient is not an Activity class ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: extent your ChatClient class to Activity and then do as @Kesh1234 said.

Answer (score 1):

To run another activity when button is clicked you just need to add this code in your onClick method:

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the buttons onClick() method write this.

```
String[] args = {};
ChatClient.main(args);
```

Comment: @Chatastropher, did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

> Your ChatClient.java is not an Activity, it is a Java class, so you
>   can call the class by instantiating it in the MainActivity2.java class.

```
ChatClient clientChat = new ChatClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy just put an `Intent` in an `onClick` of your `button`. There are 2 ways:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirtsActivity.this, SecondActivity);
    startActivity(intent);
```

or:

```
   startActivity(new Intent(FirtsActivity.this, SecondActivity));
```

Put this in your `onCreate` method of your first `activity`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirtsActivity.this, SecondActivity);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following code.

for start new activity

```
Intent chatActivity=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChatActivity.class);
                    String message=etMessage.getText().toString();
                    chatActivity.putExtra("message", message);
                    startActivity(chatActivity);
```

get data in chat activity.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            txtMessage.setText(message);
```

and for start another activity add activity tag in applicatin in manifesh.xml file like,

```
<activity android:name=".ChatActivity" />
```

Comment: Instead of punting bunch of code try highlight only required code and explain it.